# How to show result in the window (Tkinter) - "AttributeError" after running a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have already written a script, that should calculate an intersected point (xp, yp) based on different variables (xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, xd, yd) and draw segments with points in coordinate system. Generaly it works, but there is one problem. I would like to show my result (xp, yp) in window Tkinter after clickig button "Oblicz", but after implement `self.xp.set(XP)` I get an error `AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute 'set'`. What is wrong with it? How can I amend it?

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Przecinanie prostych")

        vcmd = master.register(self.validate) # we have to wrap the command
        self.entry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd,
        '%P'))

        self.zamknij_button = Button(master,
        text='Zamknij',command=master.quit)
        #draw result**
        self.rysuj_button = Button(master, text='    Rysuj    ',
        command=lambda:self.draw())
        #show result**
        self.oblicz_button = Button(master, text='  Oblicz  ',
        command=lambda:self.update())

    # LAYOUT ONLY
        self.xp = DoubleVar()
        self.yp = DoubleVar()
        self.xa_label = Label(master, text="XA")
        self.xa_label.grid(row=0)
        self.ya_label = Label(master, text="YA")
        self.ya_label.grid(row=1)
        self.xb_label = Label(master, text="XB")
        self.xb_label.grid(row=2)
        self.yb_label = Label(master, text="YB")
        self.yb_label.grid(row=3)
        self.xc_label = Label(master, text="XC")
        self.xc_label.grid(row=4)
        self.yc_label = Label(master, text="YC")
        self.yc_label.grid(row=5)
        self.xd_label = Label(master, text="XD")
        self.xd_label.grid(row=6)
        self.yd_label = Label(master, text="YD")
        self.yd_label.grid(row=7)

        self.e7_label = Label(master, text="XP")
        self.e7_label.grid(row=9)
        self.e7 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.xp)
        self.e7.grid(row = 9, column = 1)


        self.e8_label = Label(master, text="YP")
        self.e8_label.grid(row=10)
        self.e8 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.yp)
        self.e8.grid(row = 10, column = 1)


        self.zamknij_button.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)
        self.oblicz_button.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        self.rysuj_button.grid(row=11, column = 2, sticky=W, pady=4)

        self.xa = Entry(master)
        self.ya = Entry(master)
        self.xb = Entry(master)
        self.yb = Entry(master)
        self.xc = Entry(master)
        self.yc = Entry(master)
        self.xd = Entry(master)
        self.yd = Entry(master)
        self.xp = Entry(master)
        self.yp = Entry(master)

        self.xa.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.ya.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.xb.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.yb.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.xc.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.yc.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.xd.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.yd.grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.xp.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.yp.grid(row=10, column=1)

        self.xa.insert(10, 0)
        self.ya.insert(10, 0)
        self.xb.insert(10, 10)
        self.yb.insert(10, 10)
        self.xc.insert(10, 0)
        self.yc.insert(10, 10)
        self.xd.insert(10, 10)
        self.yd.insert(10, 0)

    def validate(self, new_text):
        if not new_text:  # the field is being cleared
            self.xp.set(0)
            return True

        try:
            self.xp.set(int(new_text))
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def update(self):
        xa = float(self.xa.get())
        ya = float(self.ya.get())
        xb = float(self.xb.get())
        yb = float(self.yb.get())
        xc = float(self.xc.get())
        yc = float(self.yc.get())
        xd = float(self.xd.get())
        yd = float(self.yd.get())

        dXAB = xb - xa
        dXCD = xd - xc
        dXAC = xc - xa
        dYAB = yb - ya
        dYCD = yd - yc
        dYAC = yc - ya
        mian = dXAB * dYCD - dYAB * dXCD
        t1 = (dXAC * dYCD - dYAC * dXCD) / mian

        if mian == 0:
            raise Exception('Brak przeciec')

        XP = xa + t1 * dXAB
        self.xp.set(XP)
        print XP

        YP = ya + t1 * dYAB
        self.yp.set(YP)
        print YP

    def draw(self):
        xa = float(self.xa.get())
        ya = float(self.ya.get())
        xb = float(self.xb.get())
        yb = float(self.yb.get())
        xc = float(self.xc.get())
        yc = float(self.yc.get())
        xd = float(self.xd.get())
        yd = float(self.yd.get())
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.axis([-2, xd + 2, -2, yb + 2])
        t1 = [[xa, ya], [xb, yb]]
        t2 = [[xc, yc], [xd, yd]]
        plt.plot(
            *zip(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(t1, 2))),
            color='blue', marker='o')
        plt.plot(
            *zip(*itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(t2, 2))),
            color='green', marker='o')
        ax.annotate('A', xy=(xa, ya), xytext=(xa-0.7, ya), fontsize=18)
        ax.annotate('B', xy=(xb, yb), xytext=(xb - 0.7, yb), fontsize=18)
        ax.annotate('C', xy=(xc, yc), xytext=(xc - 0.7, yc), fontsize=18)
        ax.annotate('D', xy=(xd, yd), xytext=(xd + 0.3, yd), fontsize=18)
        plt.show()

root = Tk()
my_gui = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. You are calling `set` on an entry widget, but the entry widget doesn't have a `set` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are initially creating `self.xp` and `self.yp` as  `DoubleVar` objects:

```
        self.xp = DoubleVar()
        self.yp = DoubleVar()
```

However, you later replace them with `Entry` widgets:

```
        self.xp = Entry(master)
        self.yp = Entry(master)
```

What you probably wanted to do was to create separate objects for the `Entry` widgets, and wire them up to `self.xp` and `self.yp`, by replacing the last two lines above with the following:

```
        self.xp_entry = Entry(master, textvariable=self.xp)
        self.yp_entry = Entry(master, textvariable=self.yp)
```

You would also need to replace the calls to `self.xp.grid` and `self.yp.grid` with the equivalent calls on `self.xp_entry.grid` and `self.yp_entry.grid`, i.e.:

```
        self.xp_entry.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.yp_entry.grid(row=10, column=1)
```

Once I had made these changes to your code it appeared to work, in that I could click the 'Oblicz' button and it would do some calculations and change the value of the `XP` and `YP` text fields instead of raising an exception.

Comment: That was something I missed. Now everything works. Thank you!